# Where did https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin just install to?

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu

I just ran the following three commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo su bitcoinuser
sudo apt-get install bitcoind
```

and I believe bitcoind has been installed on my Ubuntu 12.10 64Bit ec2 box, but the problem is I can't find it anywhere.

Where does bitcoin download to when installed via the ppa?

Comment: More an ubuntu question than a bitcoin one...

Comment: why do you do "su bitcoinuser"? I'm curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as all applications you install using Aptitude (`apt-get`), it is installed somewhere in a `/usr` subdirectory. However, where exactly doesn't matter because you can run those programs just by typing them in the command line.

Thus, you can launch them by typing in your Terminal either `bitcoind` for the server daemon or `bitcoin-qt` for the GUI Wallet. Also, most desktop manager automatically place a shortcut for all apps in their app menu; for Ubuntu Unity, you can just type "bitcoin" in your Dash to find Bitcoin-Qt GUI wallet app.

Just as most apps, it makes a folder in your home directory to save the data it uses. Both `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-qt` save all the block chain data in a `~/.bitcoin/` folder. You wallet is thus saved in `~/.bitcoin/wallet.dat`.